# Is it possible to get the latex version rather than pdf version of papers?

Tags: sourcecode, learning

I am going to learn latex, I think the quickest way to do it is to imitate good latex examples. The latex version of the published papers are excellent examples, is it possible to download the latex version of the published paper, and how, could  anybody give some websites or other resources?

Added: According to comments, any good tex code example without restricting to the source code of publised paper is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You can get the TeX code for many of the papers on the arXiv. Whether or not they are really a source of good TeX code is another question.

Comment: On the arXiv you can usually also download the source of the paper. Click on the "Other Formats" download link on the top right of the abstract page (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04981; you will be directed to https://arxiv.org/format/1906.04981) and then select "Download source". This downloads a gzipped version of the source code archive. Add `.gz` to the file download and unpack it. It should be noted that it can't be guaranteed in all instances that the code follows best practices or is a good example to learn from.

Comment: This is basically off-topic for us: for a start, there is no reason to expect that any arbitrary paper is even written in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of arxiv, I'll try it. I want to get the tex code of papers because I think it's probably the most convenient way to get Tex examples. Other resourses of good Tex examples are appreciated.

Comment: @苏东远 Please be aware that the latex source of a random paper is not necessarily an example for good code.

Comment: @moewe this is exactly what I want, thanks.